# undefined index id.. PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to delete some data from a table in a mysqli database, and I receive that error. I tried with isset, writing it directly without using a variable, nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

echo"hello";

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "documents");

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$ID = $_POST['id'];

$result =  mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM document WHERE id='$ID'");


header("Location: connect-db.php");
?>
```

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` and post its value

Comment: add echo $ID = $_POST['id']; 
check id print or not ...

Comment: put like $ID =isset( $_REQUEST['id']) ?  $_REQUEST['id'] : 0;

Comment: @Saty, it says: Array( ). but in the url i can see the right id "id=57".

Comment: Use`$_GET['id'];` But you are  open of sql injection check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 to prevent it

Comment: use $ID= $_REQUEST['id'];

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya, the error dissapeared but it doesn't delete it.

Comment: coz you are getting id from url so use put like $ID =isset( $_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : 0;  OR put like $ID =isset( $_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;,then check it will work

Comment: yeeey. it works. thank you so much. When I'm doing the update I receive the same error, but also for my other atributes of a document: author, title, etc. Should I write he same things there?

Comment: yes for all post and get variable we have to do same things, check "isset"

Comment: it works. thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fetching id from **`URL`** then use

```
$ID =isset( $_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : 0;
```

**OR**

```
$ID =isset( $_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
```

If you are fetching id from **`POST`** variables then use

```
$ID =isset( $_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : 0;
```

`$ _REQUEST` , `$ _POST` or `$ _GET` are special functions of PHP that are used to get variables from a user-filled form. While using these functions, a user may encounter an error - Notice: Undefined index. This error can be avoided with the help of PHP isset (). so  you just have to check if the index exists or not before you use them.

Comment: Please fill free to UV answer if this is helpful to you :) thanks

Comment: @AndrB , please check my updated answer :)

Comment: trying, but not enough reputation :| i'm pretty new to stackoverflow, hope UV means what I think it means, cuz if not I don't know :))